How do I change the font color of this chart in chart.js
How do I change the font color of this chart in chart.js?
can anybody help me
this is my code:
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
// Chart.defaults.color = '#000';
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['JS', 'Html', 'Css', 'Node.js', 'Java', ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'How much I master each language',
            data: [60, 70, 40, 10, 30],
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#09dbbf',
            color: '#faebd7'
        }],
        label:{

        }
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display:true,
            fontSize:30,
            text:"How much I master each language",
            color: '#faebd7',
            fontColor:'#faebd7'
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
            },
        },
        
        
    }
});
Chart.defaults.color = '#f00';

I'm a beginner in programming
I've looked at the library documentation and haven't found anything that helps me.

The information about colors is clear in the documentation, see colors for default color; also various items like title, legend labels, scale ticks, etc. have in their doc sections info on how to set their text colors. Your code is actually using many of that, with some mistakes; this fiddle makes corrections and adds some supplemental coloring.

You have all the info in the documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html)
For example, if you want the title with red color:
options: {
        ...
        plugins: {
            title: {
                text: "Title of chart",
                display: true,
                color: "#ff0000"
            }
        }
}

